# How to swap out masterviews in a UISplitviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

Basically, I have two MasterViewControllers for a splitViewController,but I am only able to run the app with one of them at a time. Both MasterViewControllers are using the same DetailViewController.
When the user push a tabbarbutton, the second masterViewController is pushed.

The splitViewController is straight forward declared like this in the AppDelegate

```
MasterViewControllerOne *mvc1 = [[MasterViewControllerOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewControllerOne_iPad" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *masterOneNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc1];

DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];

self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterOneNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

During runtime, I want MasterViewControllerTwo to swap with MasterViewControllerOne

Action to push the new view controller:

```
MasterViewControllerTwo*mvc2=[[MasterViewControllerTwo alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewControllerTwo_iPad" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc2 animated:YES];
```

This swaps in the mvc2 on top of mvc1. However, tapping the rows of the tableview in mvc2 does not  activate the DetailViewController.

To activate the DetailView (identical for mvc1 and mvc2) I do following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *theItem =[[self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [self.detailViewController setLabelsForItems:theItem];
}
```

Works very well as long the MasterViewController is defined in the appdelegate as member of the splitviewcontrollers array. So why doesn't the mvc2 activate the DetailViewController when it is on top of the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tapping the rows of the tableview in mvc2 does not activate the
>   DetailViewController

Well, that isn't going to happen magically all by itself. It's up to you to respond when a row of the second table view is selected. You haven't shown any code for doing that, so one assumes you have none.

In other words, a split view controller does nothing in and of itself except for containing the master and the detail. Communicating between the master and the detail is up to you. The template shows you the sort of thing you'll need to do.

Comment: the code is inside MasterViewControllerTwo, and it is exactly the same code as for MasterViewControllerOne

Comment: Yes, but *show* the code. No one can really tell you what's wrong with it unless you are willing to say what "it" *is*. Of course one could just guess as to what you might be doing wrong, but why guess? Show what you are doing as part of your question. Be specific, not vague.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I have now added the code I use to activate the DetailViewController when tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is used.

Comment: Have you added logging? Make sure this method is actually being called. If it is, I bet you dollars to donuts that self.detailViewController is nil.

Comment: You were damn right. Owe you dollars and donuts, self.detailViewController is nil. A little more research put me on the track on the protocol: SubstitutableDetailViewController. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know anything about the protocol. What I know is that Cocoa programming really all boils down to events and references. When nothing is happening, it's usually because either (1) your method isn't being called (or not being called when you think it is) or (2) you don't have a reference to the thing you think you have a reference to. Nothing happens in either case: in (1), no code runs, and in (2), code runs but your references are nil, and sending a message to nil does nothing (and throws no error). (2) is so important that an entire chapter of my book is devoted to it.